# cannot get to fancybox to work at all

Tags: jquery, fancybox

i feel i have done everything right but i cannot get lightbox to work at all. It is also coming up with the error that jQuery is not defined in the jQuery file.
file is http://www.lotuswebdzine.com/lotusweb/portfolio.php

Answer (score 10):

You are including fancybox before jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox-1.2.1.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Switch the two and it should work fine.

Comment: omg..how stupid!! thank you..i have tried so many things.  why is it always the simple thing that you miss

Comment: you should check this question as answered